# Nutch 1.10 - won't crawl more than 100 subdomains on same TLD

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

Nutch 1.10; There is a default set to limit the number of subdomains being crawled on a single TLD to 100. Can someone tell me how to override this default?

I did try the following in nutch-site.xml without success:

```
<property>
  <name>generate.max.per.host</name>
  <value>300</value>
</property>enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no limitation on the number of subdomains in Nutch. What makes you think so? How do you discover the subdomains?

If they are links from a single page then what's limiting you is 'db.max.outlinks.per.page' (defaults to 100). This limits any outlinks regardless of subdomains

Comment: Thank you Julien - the issue in fact was not that nutch was limited to the number of subdomains on a TLD. The reason I thought this was because I ran a facet query and only got 100 results returned. This is due to a default on the facet.limit of 100 results which I was unaware of. I set it to -1 and got all results returned.